# Amazon ECS - docker login unauthorized: authentication required

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager, amazon-ecs

I am needing to do a docker login https://docker.wso2.com. When I do so I get `"Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.wso2.com/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required"`

I am deploying WSO2 on **ECS** by following this article: https://medium.com/containermind/how-to-deploy-wso2-api-manager-on-amazon-ecs-bdc5a8d22844

So far I have run:

1. aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1
2. I ran the docker login with the returned command successfully

3.

```
docker login https://docker.wso2.com
Username: username
Password: password
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.wso2.com/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required
```

Also not sure if I need to do a build before step3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a wso2 user account for this. Create a user account here and try to login with that.

https://wso2.com/user/register

Comment: I can't believe that was the problem! I kept typing incorrect credentials. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for raising this concern! I have now updated the above article with this information!